# Aplicação Sprint boot + angular em WAR, por onde começar?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, war

Pessoal to precisando fazer uma aplicação em Spring boot pra a faculdade e gostaria por onde eu posso começar, algum tutorial dica...

Comment: Um projeto passo a passo com Spring + Angular: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb2oL4vcRzBPATmOQsYz_6SO30z2Fwlyw Ainda não foi finalizado, porém já tem várias aulas que vai te dar uma ótima base.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro começar pelo `Spring`, leia alguns livros e tente entender um pouco sobre `REST`, quando finalizar tente fazer uma `API Rest`, faça alguns testes e vá para o Angular. A documentação do Angular é ótima para iniciantes, se tiver dificuldades tem um canal no [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/rodrigobranas) muito bom.

Se já tem algum conhecimento veja se [esse](http://uaihebert.com/aplicacao-web-completa-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-e-security/) tutorial pode ajudar.